# How do I re-ask a question without it being marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I have this exact question [Exclude dependency in a profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790000/exclude-dependency-in-a-profile) with the exception that I'm asking in 2015 instead of 2009.  This is a feature that didn't exist then but may exist in new versions of Maven.  How do I ask it and avoid being marked as duplicate?

Comment: 1) draft the question, 2) _imagine_ it posted and dupe-closed 3) edit your draft as described in [Section 2 here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773 "'You discover that duplicate only looks similar...'") 4) post the _edited_ draft

Comment: Curiously, the [maven tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/maven/info) asked (prior to my suggested edit just now) users to re-tag "if you see *answers* with this tag...", rather than *questions*. That would imply that *answering* with a specific version in mind was enough to lock a question forever to that version, regardless of how it was asked. In fact, the question in question (if you see what I mean) makes no mention in the text of any version, but [was re-tagged 5 days later](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1790000/revisions), after the first answers were added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Old question, new technology, new answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258363/845092) (A comment on yet another related question has a good idea: Simply post a bounty for an update)

Answer (score 47):

Reference the older question in your question as something you found in your research, and explain how your question is different from the older question, or in what way the answers to that question don't solve your problem.

Comment: I thought proper course was to not post a dupe, and to request that the old answers be updated.

Comment: @MooingDuck If the correct solution to another problem isn't working for you, then by definition, you do not have a duplicate.  If *there is no correct solution* to another question, and it's answers don't even answer its own question, then you should not be creating a duplicate question.  That's not the situation described here though.

Comment: @Servy to me it sounds like OP is creating an exact duplicate in the hopes that it would get a different answer now. Isn't he saying "I have this exact question"?

Comment: @eis No, he's saying, "I have the same question except for this key difference".  If you ignore the "except for this key difference" part (or if the difference is not in fact "key"), then yes, they're dups.

Comment: I don't get how a different year is a difference. By that account we could just re-ask all the questions in a few years. Shouldn't the originals be updated instead?

Comment: @eis If there are no key differences, or the answers to the previous question solve his problem, then he'd be unable to explain why his post isn't a dup, meaning it would in fact be a duplicate.  Whether the difference in version is in fact a meaningful change to the question will be highly specific to that question.  Some problems are radically different between certain versions, and some just aren't.

Comment: @Servy: I see tons and tons of questions that are of the form "Hey, X didn't work in C++03, does it work in C++11?", and 99% of the time the right answer is "no."  These get closed as dupes of "Can I do X in C++".  If the language has updated, then the answers to the original answer should also be updated.

Comment: @MooingDuck So if anyone is ever doing anything in a version of the language that's not the most current, they can't ever expect to find answers on SO, because they'll all have been updated to use the most recent version?

Comment: @Servy I think this is actually a limitation of the idea of a single "accepted" answer - some questions fundamentally have multiple answers, with their own caveats. For instance, there might be a way to do it in C++03, but a *nicer* way to do it in C++11. If someone finds the old question who *is* using C++11, should they not benefit from knowledge of the improved solution?

Comment: @IMSoP That has its own limitations.  It means that every time you find a question you end up needing to sort through all of the answers to see which apply to the version that interests you.  There's also the fact that if an older answer has accrued a lot of votes, a newer, better, answer is going to struggle to rise to the top, resulting in lots of people continuing to use obsolete solutions.  It also requires everyone to go around adding to answers to basically every question on a topic every time a new version comes out.  That just doesn't happen.

Comment: @Servy True; I'm not sure what the right solution is. Where the features in new versions are supersets of features in old versions, the answers to the old question are likely also valid answers to the new question, so creating the semi-duplicate makes that information harder to find.

Comment: This answer addresses the general situation implied by the title, but not the specific situation mentioned in the question, which is actually rather more interesting, IMHO.

Comment: @MooingDuck 99% seems a bit far fetched. I've seen many questions that reask the same thing in the C++11 context and get decent, fresh, answers.

Comment: Every time I post a question where I say "this is not a duplicate of X because of Y" it constantly gets closed as a duplicate of X. Nobody reads.

Comment: @Jacob Or they don't feel that your explanation for why it's not a duplicate holds.  Just because you say that it's not a duplicate doesn't mean it really isn't.  Honestly about half of questions I see with such a statement are just duplicates, and the reason given isn't actually a difference relevant to the answer; the other half of the time the difference is actually meaningful and affects the answer to the question.

Comment: I don't know; no comment is left arguing the "not a duplicate" reasoning so I assume laziness.

Comment: @Jacob And maybe you're right, and maybe you're wrong.  Or, if there are multiple questions, it could be some of both.  Personally I'd assume competence until given a reason to believe otherwise.  If you want to assume negligence, I guess that's your decision.

Comment: People that close without comments _are_ negligent, IMO. They are the cancer.

Comment: @Jacob The close reason explains what is wrong with the question, and how to go about fixing that problem.  There's almost never a reason for redundant comments.  It sounds like you're just assuming that anyone who disagrees with you must be incompetent.  That's just not true; not even close.  It's also not a healthy mindset.

Comment: Not at all, just that someone that disagrees and doesn't explain why is either lazy, or they didn't comment because they didn't actually pay attention to my stated reason why it's not duplicated. If someone disagrees and says why, I have no problem. Must say that your assumptions about me don't reflect a healthy mindset either.

Answer (score 11):

From what I've seen it works more or less like this:  Someone asks a question "How do I do X?" (where the current version is v2.0), and it is answered in the context of version 2.0.

Later on, you want to ask "Do I do X in the same way now that I have version 3.0"?

If the answer is "Yes", then the answer is closed as a duplicate of the original, which, though weird, is right.  The question should exist, since people will search for it and wish to know the answer, but since the answers are all the same, the question disallows new answers there, and links to the existing question.

If the answer is "No", then one of two things happens:

- If the original question was explicitly version specific, new answers are posted on your question, congratulations.
- If the version of original question was implicit, existing answers should be edited to *also* include answers for the new version, and again, your new question gets closed as a duplicate of the original.

From the perspective of another person who has your question, when they search "How do I do X in version 3.0", they find your question, which either has answers, or is closed as a dupe of "How do I do X", which contains valid working answers.  Everyone wins.

Comment: Maybe some kind of mechanism for applying tags to answers, in addition to question could be helpful?  Although I expect there are so few question to which this problem applies that it would be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: @MikeofSST As I mentioned in my answer, I think this situation will arise more and more as the site ages, and major versions are released of platforms for which a significant corpus of questions already exists.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is actually something Stack Overflow doesn't handle very smoothly. The idea of closing duplicates is to encourage existing questions to be used as a permanent reference, improving them over time, rather than spreading knowledge across lots of momentary threads.

There are a number of options, but none of them seems ideal:

- Assume questions are version-agnostic, and simply add new answers when they come true. This makes it hard to draw attention to a question ("I think this might have a better answer now, but am not sure") or to a new answer ("the answer with 500 upvotes became valueless yesterday, read this one with 0 upvotes instead").
- Assume questions are version-specific, and tag to `$current_version` at the time of asking. Allow an arbitrary number of re-asks tagged to different versions. This is clearly non-ideal for cases where nothing has actually changed between the versions, since the answers will be identical, and simply leads to an ever-growing question count, rather than the intended knowledge base.
- Assume qestions are roughly version-specific, tag to `$current_version`, but close as duplicate for "similar" versions. This is problematic, because the decision to close is based on the *answers*, not the *question* - you have to know that "how do I do this in Maven 1?" is the same as "how do I do this in Maven 2?", but not the same as "how do I do this in Maven 3?".

I guess this is a relatively new problem for Stack Overflow, as many major technologies (such as programming languages) have had relatively few releases within the last 5 years.

Overall, I think the first option is the best within the framework we have - existing questions are not frozen in time. New answers can be added, and old answers updated with new information, and this is part of the model. It only feels wrong if you consider the aim to get the single best answer to each question; the rest is just the practicality of making things visible.

Comment: You might be interested in this question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks, I guess I should really have searched for duplicates before posting! :)