# Should I ask a question that has already been asked but for legacy technology?

Tags: discussion

So I want to know if it is acceptable (within the rules) to ask a question that has already been asked for an older version of the technology at hand. Also the solution to the other question may of been correct at the time but it no longer works.

Possible options:

- Make a new but very similar question, while linking that other one.
- Attempt to edit the older question (This seems horrible as the older question should be kept for historic reasons).
- Suggestions?

Please answer the question in a more general sense and use my situation purely as an example. Thanks.

**My specific situation/question:**

Somebody has already asked a question that is almost identical to mine here: [Visual Studio 2012: change setting for “Enable floating tab wells”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396596/visual-studio-2012-change-setting-for-enable-floating-tab-wells)

However, that question is for Resharper version 7.1 and the answers provided do not appear to solve the same problem with Resharper version 9.

Comment: possible duplicate of  [Old question, new technology, new answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer) Or maybe this from the answerer's point: [Good question, old version-dependent answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) Or this: [How do I re-ask a question without it being marked as a duplicate?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283470/how-do-i-re-ask-a-question-without-it-being-marked-as-a-duplicate)

Comment: @Deduplicator Ah, thank you I searched around for a while looking for any potential duplicates.....Evidently your stack overflow search skills are superior. Quick question, should I delete this question now since it is simply a duplicate?

Comment: No need, just leave it. It's quite well-written. If you already had the rep, voting to close would be in order though. BTW: This was my search: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=new+version+question+is%3Aq