# Old question, same technology, not satisfied by the answer. What to do?

Tags: discussion, old-questions

I was happy to find that [the exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853987/how-to-depict-nested-action-activities-in-a-uml-activity-diagram) I have has already been asked and answered. However, I'm not fully satisfied by the answer (and the OP doesn't seem to be satisfied either). What should I do to give this question some more attention from the people who follow those tags?

Would it be correct to repost the same question? Or is there a way to make it appear on top of the question list again?

In [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer) the answers says it's correct to create a new question if the technology changed, but I don't think it's the case here.

I could of course start a bounty, but I wonder if there's another way.

Comment: Repost maybe - but only if you can ask the question in a better way. Be wary not to willingly create a duplicate.

Comment: Well, the only difference between my question and the one I link is that I don't use the same software. This would clearly be a duplicate, and I wouldn't add that much quality to the question since it's already pretty good.

Comment: Agreed. The original question looks very good, to be honest. But if I read the comment train on the answer, I get the idea that there may have been a case of an X/Y problem going on. Wanting to do something in a way that is not according to the design of the tool. If that is the case, no bounty is ever going to produce a satisfying answer.

Comment: Ask a new question, explain what's different about your case and why the existing answer(s) don't work for you. Be very clear and explicit about this, so it doesn't get closed as a duplicate. Alternatively, of course, you could use a bounty. This is only appropriate if you really have exactly the same problem as the person who asked the original question. Otherwise, it gets very confusing if the bounty message is asking a slightly different question than the, um, question.

Comment: Thanks, I [just did it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572229/how-to-represent-nested-actions-in-an-uml-activity-diagram) . I hope it's clearer in this one, though it still strongly looks like a duplicate.

Comment: (Fun fact: The person who correctly answered [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572229/how-to-represent-nested-actions-in-an-uml-activity-diagram) is the same as the one who answered  [the old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853987/how-to-depict-nested-action-activities-in-a-uml-activity-diagram). This time, the answer suits my needs)

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the re-asking clause from your question, because the very first line should be clear enough. Remember, try to treat Stack Overflow as a general Q&A site; not as a discussion forum of  some sort.

Comment: Well of course excepting Meta. (But that's open to discussion.)

Comment: @RadLexus You've done well. There were too much lines before really coming to the topic. Thanks :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Please post your comment as an answer.  It makes a lot of sense. [Wheaties current accepted answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334817/691711) only covers the case where the question is *exactly* the same.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Bounty sounds like the exact solution to your problem. If the question is the same and the tech is the same, getting the attention of people can be accomplished on SO by adding a bounty. The other option is to post a link in social media or websites where people might contribute.

Comment: I thought so, anyway reposting the question already worked. Not sure I have to accept this answer then :/ Maybe add Cody Gray's comment to your answer so I can accept it ? Concerning the social media part, I once saw a guy being badly treated on LinkedIn while posting a link to his question on a specialized group. Not sure I'd try it.

Comment: @TimF Accepting an answer on meta is pretty much optional, it doesn't do very much ;)

Comment: @TimF If someone posted a link to their LinkedIn profile in a question on SO they would be treated just as bad. Needless to say, you could simply copy your question there instead of adding it as an external link, if you expect somebody to be able to give an answer.

Comment: And upvote the question, of course :-)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I always try to be the first one to upvote my question's answers ;)

Answer (score 5):

That answer in your example was not accepted, and even if it was, if it is the wrong answer, it should not be used a dupe. The reason being this question will never be answered short of a bounty, and bounties are fairly rare.

That said, you probably should link that question in your question and explain why it does not solve your problem.

Bounty is also a valid option, but I don't believe it is the only appropriate way to get a correct answer to an existing question that has not been correctly answered.