# How to bring attention to a new answer on an old overly answered question

Tags: support, answers, old-questions

I'm talking about the question [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill/51656048#).

I got stuck for quite some time on this subject and I decided to look into it myself, since the answers to this question won't work. *(The `autocomplete` attribute doesn't seem to be doing much on Chrome's last versions)*

After a while I found a solution that was working for me and everyone that tried it so far.

I posted it as an answer, but since the question has 80 answers in total, I feel like my answer won't be seen by anyone.

I really think it could help a lot of people.

Is there a way for me to change that?

Comment: Why does it have 80 answers in the first place? That's a red flag for *too broad*.

Comment: Not really, that is an example of failed Q+A.  You *might* be able to convince mike nelson to merge your solution into his post.  He seems willing to keep his post updated and is still around.  Add a comment to make him aware.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you I'll go do that right away.

Comment: @Stijn I think it's more because the answer to this question changes with every browser/browser version. Meaning it changes a lot. A whole lot.

Comment: Remember that there's an entire [page dedicated to **N**ew **A**nswers **T**o **O**ld questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions), where your answer would be present for all the 10k+ users to check and verify.

Comment: If the accepted answer became a community wiki, it would be able to be upkept by the community, right?

Comment: I had good luck answering a popular question 7 years after it was asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36027429/5987

Comment: @BhargavRao Thank you for this information, I didn't know about that. So I guess I just have to wait?

Comment: Simply answer the question.

Comment: @KevinB Already did ?

Comment: Great! you're done then.

Comment: Seems like the question wasn't understood :')

Comment: well, no, not at all. I don't think you need to bring more attention to it. If it's a good answer, it will naturally get attention. If it isn't, it wont. You can apply a bounty if you want, but that will simply bring attention to the question and all the answers, not just yours. The same goes with sharing it.

Comment: My point was that it won't get any attention since there's so many. But that was before I knew there was a queue for 10k+ users. So maybe it'll change things, I'll wait and see.

Comment: It being the most recently active answer, it will naturally sit at the top of the list for anyone sorting the answers by activity.

Comment: This has been raised many times in meta: https://github.com/cirosantilli/write-free-science-books-to-get-famous-website/tree/80921ec9010ce6fa3996ee86386b8b032d0889fd#newer-is-better

Comment: *"the answer to this question changes with every browser/browser version. Meaning it changes a lot. A whole lot."* And are you sure you are willing to update yours at every releases of every browser? I agree this is a problem, but I don't think your meta-post here actually asks the good question. What we should find is not "how to *bump* my currently correct answer", but *"how to deal with on-topic and good questions for which the answer will keep changing over-time"*

Answer (score 3):

> I feel like my answer won't be seen by anyone.

What makes you think so?

> ...the answers to this question won't work.
>
> After a while I found a solution that was working for me and everyone that tried it so far... I posted it as an answer...

If "the answers to this question" *really* "won't work", while yours does, anyone with this problem will try them in succession until they hit yours and succeed. (They may give up before then, but then they won't solve their problem. Besides, due to the many downvoted answers, a newly-posted one will not be the last in the list.)

---

Alternatively, you can look at he ways that [Good question, old version-dependent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265433/good-question-old-version-dependent-answer) advises. They include (but only as a second option to the above advice!):

- asking a new question *if you have, and prominently describe, valid reasons (listed there) for why the old question* (the question, not the answers!) *does not apply.* In any case, the community may disagree with you on your judgement and still mark your question as a duplicate.

  - *One possible way* is to formulate the new question like this:

    > *Disabling Autofill in Chrome vXX+*
    >
    > In [Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill), none of about 80 (!) answers for various Chrome versions (I see v48 to v63 mentioned) work anymore in vXX. In particular, these ways no longer work:
    >
    > - [`autocomplete="false"` or `"new-password"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30976223/648265)
    > - Autogenerated field IDs
    > - fake fields, either [hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917221/648265) or [off-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38406667/648265)
    > - [presetting field values, then cleaning them after load](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30824079/648265)
    > - (etc for other options)
    >
    > What is the new way to fix/work around this problem?
- adding notes to existing solutions that no longer work. Either as a comment, or, *if you have a valid reason to think that the solution really doesn't work and it's not just you or your different environment* (e.g. there's an existing comment to this effect with many upvotes) -- as an obsolescence note, e.g.:

  > **Obsolescence note:** no longer works as of <version>

Comment: They will try all 80 of them ? That's optimistic ^^

Comment: @Zenoo not all. Until they hit one that works for them. They may give up before then, but then they won't solve their problem.

Comment: @Zenoo Besides, there are many downvoted answers there, so a newly-posted one won't be the last in the list.

Comment: The comment trick. That's why I do.

Answer (score -23):

## Post a new question and answer it.

Link to the orginal question and explain that the solutions don't work anymore. Tag the new question with a browser version if possible.

The question should have been split into several version-specific questions from the beginning, because, as it is obvious now, there is not a single answer that works for all versions. Having answers to different versions in the same question makes sorting by votes useless and finding the relevant answer much harder.

The same question for different versions are not duplicates of each other if there is no answer that works for both.

(The most-upvoted answer in [this, more general meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258363/old-question-new-technology-new-answer) advises the same.)

Comment: We definitely do not need a different question for every web problem for every different browser and version number. It's the same question with the same technology, the answer has just changed over time due to changes in that technology.

Comment: Why not? It makes searching much easier. When looking at the question with 4 answer pages: Is this really what we want?

Comment: I don't think a question per browser/browser version would be advisable, to be honest. That would make hundreds of them. A single question with a detailed and updated answer every time a change has come would be good.

Comment: There should be a new question only when the old answers don't work anymore, I hope that's not hundreds, @Zenoo . But I agree it's not optimal either - but I really only see the two options of posting to the old Q or asking a new one - and thought a new Q/A would be better.